# Fill_Between returns ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I would like to fill the area under the curve in this plot over the range x=0 to x < 3. But I get `ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = [1,2,3]
y=[10,20,30]
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y, where=x<3, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is trying to create a boolean mask with a standard python list. If you cast `x` and `y` to `numpy.array`, then all should work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1)
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([10,20,30])
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y, where=x<3, facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If `x` is a python list, `x<3` returns `False`, but `fill_between`'s `where` keyword requires an `N-length` numpy boolean array.

```
In [89]: x=[1,2,3]

In [91]: x<3
Out[91]: False

In [92]: x=np.array(x)

In [93]: x<3
Out[93]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that this is a python legacy (2) problem, as in py3 `[1, 2, 3] < 3` raises a `TypeError`.  The `False` result is due to python falling back to comparing the object `id` (iirc, might be memory address) as a last resort so I am not sure that is even deterministic.